# Nested Angular material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have a requirement for adding dynamic tabs to some `User Preferences` screen.
The main preference tab can be a static tab with static content, but the second tab should have nested `mat-tab` elements.

These additional dynamic preferences come from the backend, which then allows me to use an `*ngFor` to render the extra tabs.

Problem I'm seeing now is with the tab `labels`. The label text is taking its value from the first nested tab, and NOT from the `label` property I'm setting.

Please see my example here on stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-nested?embed=1&file=app/tab-group-async-example.html

A code snippet from the online project is:

```html
<mat-tab-group>

...

<mat-tab label="More Dynamic Preferences">

    <!-- NESTED HERE -->    
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs | async">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
        {{tab.content}}
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>

  </mat-tab>
  
</mat-tab-group>
```

If you click on "More Dynamic Preferences" tab, then the tab header text becomes "First". Same happens on the second tab, whose tab content I'm loading synchronous, as opposed to the async example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This issue is being caused by the way label is being set for tab.

You are setting label of parent with attribute label however for child tab you had used the template way to define it.

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>
```

So what you can do is either you define the label of parent tab same or just add label attribute for the child tabs too.

Here is working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-nested-n77qed

Comment: I was having an issue using `ng-template` on the nested tab. It wasn't rendering. I'll review your code. thanks.

Comment: I was using  `<ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</ng-template>` as per their examples online, but just using the `label` prop seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `<ng-template>`s are in the `<mat-tabs>` elements, but after removing those, add some bindings to the `label` input of the tab components, and refactoring the async call to not use `setTimeout()` and use native rxjs operations, I have a working demo of using nested tabs with dynamic tab creation:

```
  <mat-tab label="Customer Preferences"> 
    <h2>HERE ARE YOUR PREFERENCES</h2>
  </mat-tab> 

  <mat-tab label="Dynamic Preferences">
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of prefTabs" [label]="tab.label">
        {{tab.content}}
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="More Dynamic Preferences">
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of asyncTabs | async" [label]="tab.label">
        {{tab.content}}
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
```

[Updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-nested-e8m4rk)

Comment: ng-template inside mat-tabs are used to lazy load the content of the tab container