# angular recursive ng-template with- display in UI only children of item that is pressed

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a recursive ng-template:

```
<ng-template #recursiveNavList let-tabs="tabs" let-level="level">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index">
                <a mat-tab-link
                   [routerLink]="[tab.category.facet]"
                   #rla="routerLinkActive"
                   [active]="rla.isActive"
                   routerLinkActive>
                        <span>
                            {{tab.category}}
                        </span>
                </a>

                <div *ngIf="tab.subCategories.length > 0 && (rla.isActive || tab.category.facet==='all')">
                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveNavList; context: { tabs: tab.subCategories, level: level + 1}"></ng-container>
                </div>

            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveNavList; context: { tabs: facetService.facets, level:0}"></ng-container>
```

my json look like-

```
[
{"category":{"facet":"inProcess","count":"1"},"subCategories":[]},
{"category":{"facet":"all","count":"2"},"subCategories":[{"category":{"facet":"conference","count":"2"},"subCategories":[{"category":{"facet":"paper","count":"1"},"subCategories":[]},{"category":{"facet":"poster","count":"1"},"subCategories":[]}]}]}
]
```

I should display sub categories in the UI only if his direct parent is selected (or if it's a direct child of "all")

In the beginning I expect to see:

*inProcess
all
conference*

and after the user presses on conference he will see

*inProcess
all
conference
paper
poster*

I made an if condition on the div that calls the recursion with the sub category only is - (rla.isActive || tab.category.facet==='all)'. but the problem is that if the user clicks "poster" the conference is closed, because now the route isn't active.

Is there any simple way to add a condition to the "if" inside the "div" that a tab will remain open if one of his sub categories is open?

I try to avoid adding a click function that turns some flag on.

Comment: Transform the structure to two-level array. Don't have more than parent-child, and for each iteration display parent links and recursively children.

Comment: I cannot transform the data.. I can have multiple levels.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case your main issue is active state of nested tabs - there already is such an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194896/nested-angular-material-tabs?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: not exactly, my problem is how to recognize that a tab has one nested tab that in mode active